# « Et là, je vois que le Dictionnaire de la langue française donne du subversif [...] » : comment donne-t-il au juste ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, verbes, lexique, transitivité

Dans un [article](http://www.lapresse.ca/arts/livres/201710/20/01-5140721-dany-laferriere-le-dictionnaire-grand-roman-de-laventure-humaine.php), on rapporte un entretien avec l'écrivain et académicien (F2) Dany Laferrière dont voici un extrait :

> C'est extraordinaire, dit-il. Je n'étais pas un fan du dictionnaire,
>   même si je suis écrivain. Et là, je vois que le *Dictionnaire de la
>   langue française* **donne du** subversif, ce que je soupçonnais! Car
>   quand on connaît la signification des mots! Simplement savoir que
>   l'origine du mot "travail" vient de torture, [...]
>
> [ *Dany Laferrière: le dictionnaire, «grand roman de l'aventure
>   humaine»* dans La Presse, 2017-10-20 ]

- *[Donner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donner) du* subversif, à quel emploi/sens de *donner* ça se rattache au juste, qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ? C'est comme dans *donner du [coude](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/coude/19709/locution?q=donner%20du%20coude#153902)* ?

  - Est-ce la même chose que *donner dans*, au figuré (TLFi II A 3 a, b ;
    4 : *croire à/céder à, avoir du goût/un penchant pour ; se laisser
    aller à, être orienté vers*) ?

Comment: On dirait que "subversif" (which I'd have called an adjective) est "devenu" (une espèce de?) substantif ici. (Is creating nouns directly from adjectives in French  like this "normal" [i.e., "can be done at will"]? If not, could this have something to do with this use of "donner"? ie, "cela donne du [adjective/eg,subversif]"="cela fait chic/subversif"?)

Answer (score 2):

Finalement, je suis tenté sérieusement à croire (comme vous [vous] demandiez ailleurs en commentaire) qu’en effet, «[l’on a] simplement ici le sens primaire de *donner*», c’est-à-dire (pour moi):
 «Faire don, **offrir**»,
 comme dans:

> Ce livre (voire plutôt: cette [grande] œuvre) **offre** du subversif
>   [de la lecture subversive] à ses lecteur/trices.

C’est vrai que, d’habitude, on cite/liste plus qu’une seule chose quand on parle de ce qu’un livre peut «nous offrir», comme dans:

> [Ce livre offre du vécu, de la réflexion, des
>   perspectives;](https://books.google.com/books?id=cjrr0NuBhIsC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=%22ce+livre+offre+du%22&source=bl&ots=DeFHlADH81&sig=340nQJ9KIa8gU9xKRLQo1k7FH08&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0yae3l4fXAhWDSiYKHR4wAB4Q6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=%22ce%20livre%20offre%20du%22&f=false)
>
> (de la Préface de *Une Afrique s'invente: recherches populaires et
>   apprentissages démocratiques*, via *GoogleBooks*)

Et cette «liste» d’un seul mot/offre me fait repenser sérieusement cette réponse, mais peut-être la notion [subversive?) que **le** *Dictionnaire de la langue française* peut être (ou du moins peut offrir du) subversif est suffisante toute seule pour en faire une "liste."

Comment: Merci ! Je vois ça un peu plus comme _reading this will give (one, you, the reader) courage_ ou _will make the reader + adj._, since they will know the origin of these words, for instance _work_ stemming from the idea of _torture_ etc. C'est possiblement davantage _rend le lecteur subversif_ qui correspond le plus à mon interprétation finale, le sens d'_offrir_ est possible mais ne « transforme » pas ou n'a pas d'impact sur le lecteur, et _offrir_ serait à mon avis plus usuel comme tel que donner, comme ds. votre exemple. Ça fait finalement trois interprétations de tout ça, j'adore :) Merci !

Comment: ... s'aventurer dans qqch., offrir qqch. à qqn, et rendre qqn. davantage/ajouter à la personne qqch...

Comment: @Galèrefranquiste Maybe I missed/am missing something, but the expressions in the last comment that I see (s'aventurer dans qqch., offrir qqch. à qqn, et rendre qqn. davantage/ajouter à la personne qqch) are all good, especially "s'aventurer dans qqch.", which made me think immediately of "**to delve into** [something/the subversive]" in English, although working back to French from that would probably be best captured by "fouiller dans," which only seems to be getting further and further away from "donner." Oh well!

Comment: This _s'aventurer dans_ comes from jlliagre's A. & comment and _offrir_ is from yours, whereas _rendre_ is mine. I read yours a bit like _to provide_. Delves into, right, I thought veers to, but when I checked that verb it wasn't exactly what I thought it was or is not necessarily idiomatic in context. _Donner dans_ I easily associate with something like _le dramatique_, it's very close to a meaning _faire_ can have, _faire dans_, almost _fall into_, glisser. There is this idea imho that you're within something and then you go overboard or it overflows into sth. else, by exaggerating. Tks!

Answer (score 1):

***Donne du*** subversif est ici l'équivalent du plus courant  ***donne dans*** le subversif, c'est à dire, se laisse aller à, s'aventure dans des écrits subversifs. Il s'agit ici bien sûr d'un trait d'humour de Dany Laferrière.

cf. [**Donner** TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donner) :

> II.− Emploi intrans.
>   A.− [Implique une idée de direction vers et de contact, de choc]
>   3. *Au fig*. **Donner dans**.
>   b) Avoir du goût, un penchant pour; se laisser aller à. *Donner dans un vice, un défaut; donner dans la dévotion, le luxe. Ces prétendus hommes charitables, qui font les confits, qui vont à la messe, qui donnent dans la prêtraille* (Hugo, *Misér.*,t. 1, 1862, p. 894). *Je croyais que papa ne donnait pas dans la jeune fille... D'habitude, il est pour femmes mariées, ou pour grues* (Colette, Cl. Paris,1901, p. 258):
>   63. Myrto, spirituelle, bonne et jolie, mais qui **donne** dans le chic, préfère à ses autres amies Parthénis, qui est duchesse et plus brillante qu'elle... Proust, *Les Plaisirs et les jours*, 1896, p. 68.
>   − *Spéc. Donner dans le ridicule*. ,,Se rendre ridicule`` (Ac.).

Comment: Quelle que soit l'interprétation (*du = de le* ou *dans le*), *subversif* est ici un substantif pour *des idées subversives* ou *des écrits subversifs*. Ce qui m'incite à penser que le sens est plus proche de *s'aventure dans* que de *donne, délivre, fournit*, c'est que la première hypothèse traduit un effet plus comique en personnifiant le dictionnaire. Cela dit, les sens sont somme toute assez voisins. PS: On peut se tutoyer sur FSE.